# When UserProfile object is created for the first time?

Tags: user-profile

Environment: SP 2010 Enterprise. Claims based auth only enabled.

Is User Profile created when user signs in for the first time? Or it takes some time for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Claims can be used with Windows Authentication so I assume you mean Claims with FBA and no windows auth; correct?

With 2003 and 2007 I'm nearly positive that the user profile was created the first time a user accessed the site, but with 2010 that does not seem to be the case.  It either needs to be created through synchronization, programatically using the API or PowerShell, or it can be created when the user clicks the profile or mysite the first time.

Here is some info on creating the profiles without sync:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg188041.aspx#noSync

Comment: +1 because I just tested that 2010 doesn't add User Profile automatically